# Why does my Node.js application not stop when using --inspect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, debugging, webstorm

I have the following Node.js application here:

```
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const mysql = require("mysql2")
const path = require("path")

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE
})

connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})

connection.query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todo (id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT, todo VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY(id))", err => {
    if(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})

app.get("/todos", (req, res) => {
    connection.query("SELECT todo FROM todo", (err, results) => {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        res.status(200);
        res.send(results);
    })
})

app.post("/todo", (req, res) => {
    connection.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM todo", (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        const id = results[0].count + 1;
        connection.query("INSERT INTO todo (id, todo) VALUES (?, ?)", [id, req.body.todo], (err) => {
            if(err) {
                console.error(err);
                res.sendStatus(500);
            }
            res.status(201);
            res.send(id.toString())
        })
    })
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
})

app.get("/client.js", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client.js"))
})

app.listen(8000);
```

If I execute this server with `node --inspect` (or `--inspect-brk`) `app.js` and set a breakpoint somewhere, the application does not stop there.

I have already tried this with the code lines `const id = results[0].count + 1;` and `app.listen(8000);`. I expected the application to stop when these lines were reached. I used the application in a way which reaches these lines by sending an HTTP Post request to reach the former line and I simply started the app to reach the latter line. I tried it with WebStorm and Chrome DevTools as well. What could be the reason, why this does not work? I would be very grateful for any tips.

Comment: I don't see any `debugger` statements in the code you're showing, so you're going to have to explain exactly how you're debugging (in terms of each step you're taking. Just "I ran node with --inspect and set a breakpoint" doesn't tell folks what you _specifically_ did. [Be as detailed as possible](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: What do you mean by debugger statement? So far I have always debugged programs in other programming languages and there I was able to set breakpoints. If the program then stopped there, I could read variables or navigate through the source code in individual steps. I just wanted to try this out for Node.js and therefore set breakpoints at the specified points. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: No idea: you've not shown _where you've set a breakpoint_ nor talked about how you're doing your actual debugging after starting up `node --inspect`, so [probably add those missing details to your post](/help/how-to-ask).